# How to implement licensing model in Custom SharePoint Online Solution?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, licensing, pnpjs

We are creating one small product in SharePoint using Pnp framework and REST API. We would like to implement licensing model in product for selling purpose.

Anyone has experience with such kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [Microsoft AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com), essentially the equivalent of an "app store", but just for SharePoint online and other O365 based apps.  You want to follow the process to [register as a seller](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/partners) so you submit your PnP App.

Comment: No, I am looking to implement license like free or yearly or unlimited basis.